# Add method to a gem's helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, monkeypatching

I am using a gem which adds a number of View helpers under the following module hierarchy:

```
module Ransack
  module Helpers
    module FormHelpers
      def search_form_for
      end
    end
  end
end

ActionController::Base.helper Ransack::Helpers::FormHelper
```

I want to add my own helper method into the same module hierarchy, and make it available to all views. How do I do this?

Comment: Reopen one of those modules and add your methods?

Comment: Where should I reopen it? I'm not sure where in Rails load order would make it work, and my current experiments have all failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the point of altering the gem with additional methods? If it's a view helper, simply create an appropriate file in the `app/helpers` directory of your app and add your custom helper there.

The custom helper will be available to all views.

Comment: While that works, it feels slightly _wrong_. The method is definitely tied to the Ransack gem, not the global namespace. In fact, it needs to reference `Ransack::Helpers`` objects, meaning they need the full namespace path added to them. It should be possible to add the method in to where it belongs. That said, it _does_ work, so I'll go for it as a workaround for the moment.

Comment: Polluting a namespace which is not under your control (such as a gem) is generally not a good idea.